# what is the Recent Nature Inspired Algorithm for Optimization?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, bio-inspired-computing

I'm into designing a **recommender system** for movie database and for effective optimization.I suggested the idea of using particle swamp optimization ,but my professors need recent algorithms,can any one suggest ***recent nature inspired algorithms for optimization***.(After Cuckoo Search Optimization).

Comment: Did you look for *ant colony optimisation*?

Comment: any one ,but it should be a recent one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This paper[[1]] recommends the following Swarm Intelligence algorithms:

> 1. Ant colony optimization
> 2. Bat algorithm
> 3. Cuckoo search
> 4. Firefly algorithm
> 5. Particle swarm optimization

[1]: ["A Brief Review of Nature-Inspired Algorithms for Optimization"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.4186)

Comment: The paper suggest variety of algorithm,but suggest me a recent and new algorithm for optimization .Sorry a beginner here :)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check the IEEE Congress on Evolutionary Computation as new algorithms are published there every year. Not sure if the answer is still helpful though. You may check here [link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/mostRecentIssue.jsp?punumber=8466244) for the 2018 publications.

Answer (score 2):

Recently, optimization algorithms are being suggested based on the network dynamics of a slime mold called [*Physarum polycephalum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physarum_polycephalum). For certain problems, these algorithms provably construct optimal solutions. Have a look into the following paper for further pointers.

Yahui Sun. Physarum-inspired Network Optimization: A Review. [arXiv: 1712.02910](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.02910.pdf)